# I want to call two ContentViews from one Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making an online shopping app and When the admin uploads products to the database, the Users can see the products in the Home Page in a RecyclerView. The products are categorized as "countable" & "uncountable". And the category is being saved in the database with the product information, like this:

[image: Firebase screenshot showing an object details]

I want when a User clicks on a product in the Home Page, to open a specific Activity according to the Category type(countable or uncountable).

I tried this in the Home Page:-

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Products, ProductViewHolder> adapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Products, ProductViewHolder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final Products model)
                {
                    holder.txtProductName.setText(model.getPname());
                    holder.txtProductPrice.setText("Rs. " + model.getPrice());
                    Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).into(holder.imageView);
                    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {

                            if(model.getCategory() == "countable"){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ProductDetailsActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("pid" , model.getPid());
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }else{
                                Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, ProductDetails2Activity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("pid" , model.getPid());
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }

                        }
                    });
                }

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
                {
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_items_layout, parent, false);
                    ProductViewHolder holder = new ProductViewHolder(view);
                    return holder;
                }
            };
```

But it's not working... Can someone help me please? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: model.getCategory() .equals("countable")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `==` use `equals` ,`contains` or `equalsIgnoreCase` .

```
 if(model.getCategory().equals("countable")){

}
```